# Newt's wand error or plot hole?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

We see Newt Scamander use his wand several times in the film. Graves briefly mentions that Newt was expelled from Hogwarts. However, when Hogwarts students get expelled, their wands are destroyed by the Ministry of Magic.

Comment: Even if he was expelled, couldn't he just get another one? Surely wizards can get wands outside of being Hogwarts students?

Comment: The answer on the dupe confirms that it's neither a plot hole, nor is it an error that he still has his wand.

Answer (score -1):

**Newt Scamander was never expelled**

According to HPWiki,

> In 1913, one of Leta's experiments involving a Jarvey went too far and endangered the life of a student. Rather than see his good friend expelled, Newt took the blame and was sentenced to be expelled from Hogwarts in her place. However, Albus Dumbledore, Newt's Transfiguration teacher at the time, argued strongly on his behalf and cleared his name. The expulsion was never enforced.

Even in the movie, Graves mentions how when Newt was under threat of expulsion, it was Dumbledore who saved him. Graves wonders aloud what Newt must have done to be capable of such explicit support from Dumbledore himself.

So, Newton was never expelled, nor was his wand snapped.

Comment: If you're going to make a claim that contradicts the film and JKR's own tweets, you'll need some evidence that's better than the fan-wiki

Comment: @Valorum Brindha is contradicting OP and not necessarily the film. A definitive quote from the film would be nice, however.

Comment: @Spencer - We have multiple sources, including from JKR herself confirming that he was definitely expelled.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/amp/wizardsandwhatnot.com/2016/04/11/rowling-comments-on-newt-scamanders-expulsion-from-hogwarts/amp/?client=ms-android-hms-tef-gb

Comment: The note about the author in the textbook 'Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them' mentions that Scamander joined the MoM upon 'graduation from Hogwarts'. I guess Scamander could have lied to boost sales, but would the Board really approve a textbook that was written by someone who was expelled?